# How to resolve problems with Insufficient length on init xfdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I have problems with xfdf class init.
This code works excellent in preproduct and on my local machine.
But doesn't work in product env.

```
XfdfReader reader = new XfdfReader(getPostDataArray(request));

java.io.IOException: Insufficient length.at com.lowagie.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.lowagie.text.pdf.XfdfReader. <mit> (Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You are using [an obsolete version of iText. You shouldn't use it in production.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially) Abandon all hope because you have chosen to use a version of iText that is no longer supported. Hint: take a look at the package name `com.lowagie.*`, then take a look at my name.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie yeah, I see. :) Thanks for your nice lib. I'm using 2.1.7 v. I will check your post. Thank you.